# Delete Image uploaded Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating an image upload using Material UI. I am unable to delete the uploaded images(handleDelete).
You can find my code here :
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-confirm-demo-forked-pjhm6?file=/src/Demo.js

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter out inside `handleDelete` like this:

```
handleDelete = (name) => {
    const newState = [...this.state.names].filter((data) => !(data === name));
    this.setState({ names: newState });
  };
```

and pass name property from `Chip` like this:

```
<Chip
              size="small"
              avatar={
                <Avatar
                  alt="pre"
                  src={this.state.imagesPreviewUrls.map((imagePreviewUrl) => {
                    return <img alt="previewImg" src={imagePreviewUrl} />;
                  })}
                />
              }
              label={name}
              onDelete={() => this.handleDelete(name)}
            />
          );
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-confirm-demo-forked-e3b1t?file=/src/Demo.js:2346-2774

Comment: Thanks this actually works!! If i wanted to preview the image uploaded inside the avatar, can I map the image as I did  or is there any other way?

Comment: No you are doing correct. Just add `key` whenever you are looping any element